# Соцсети на Вордпресс

Tags: wordpress

Здравствуйте. Хочу поставить соцсети (не кнопки, а виджеты,блоки для подписки, с  фото участников) не на текстовый блок, а справа от него, на общем фоне. Там пространства много, тема landline на вордпрессе. 
Как это сделать? В админке в виджетах есть "боковая панель", но при размещении в ней на экране ничего не отображается..

Answer (score 0):

Странно, но я не вижу в теме Landline предопределенных мест для виджетов.
Добавьте места для виджетов в файл functions.php - https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgetizing_Themes
и разместите в коде шаблона страницы в нужном вам месте.

Но еще лучше используйте другой шаблон, Landline выглядит слишком устаревшим.